# Unit Testing NodeJs Controller with Axios

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, axios

I have a controller and a request file that look like this, making the requests with axios(to an external API), and sending the controller response to somewhere else, my question is, how to apply Unit Testing to my controller function (getInfoById), how do I mock the axiosRequest since it's inside the controller?. I am using Jest and only Jest for testing(might need something else, but I'm not changing)

```
file: axiosFile.js

  import axios from "axios"

  export const axiosRequest = async (name) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("url")
    return data
  }


file: controllerFile.js

  import { axiosRequest } from "./axiosFile"

  export const getInfoById = async (name) => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosRequest(name)
      return { status: 200, ...response }
    } catch {
      return { status: 500, { err: "Internal ServerError" } }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.
PS: It's a Backend in NodeJs

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the http calls using [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock)

This way you will be directly able to test your method by mocking the underlying http call. So in your case something like

```
const nock = require('nock')

const scope = nock(url)
  .get('/somepath')
  .reply(200, {
    data: {
      key: 'value'
    },
  })
```